# Projection change in QGIS after import & export in Grass

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, grass-gis, export, import

I'm working on an application written with **Grass command in python** and I have a projection problem.
First I create a location with belgian lambert 72 (EPSG:31370) in Grass 7.0.

After importing all the environment variables I run this code:

```
gscript.run_command("r.in.gdal", input=path+"initialDEM.adf",flags='o', output="DEM")
gscript.run_command("g.region",rats="DEM",res=10)
gscript.run_command("r.out.gdal",input="DEM",type='Byte',output=pathOutput+'finalDEM',overwrite=True,flags='f')
```

Now I want to import the output raster (finalDEM) in **QGIS**. And I don't know why the projection change as you can see on the picture. (in red initDEM and in blue finalDEM) 
[image]

The SCR of the raster finalDEM is `USER:100000, *SCR generated ...`. 
Do you know why I have this change of projection? Do you know how I can avoid it in my python code?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the original "initialDEM.adf" is indeed in the EPSG:31370 coordinate system? Instead of importing with the "-o" flag, try to first create a new region that matches the import DEM by running:

`r.in.gdal -c input="initialDEM.adf" location="belgium_lambert"`

Then rerun r.in.gdal **without** the "-o" flag.

BTW, what are you trying to do in the above? Changing the region then doing r.out.gdal won't change the output DEM.